# UICollectionView vertical bounce not working

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have this really strange issue and I can't seem to get my head around it.
I have a collection view with a custom layout and when I scroll from up to down, the collection view bounces but when I go to the bottom of the collection view it is simply stuck. Even the scroll indicator remains the same size.

The collection view seems to regain its expected behaviour if I go to the last collection view cell and remove some vertical constraints between the views that are inside the cell. All the cells are autoresizing.

Has anyone ran into anything similar?
[Here is a video of what is happening](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sm3bherruxrtwb5/Video%2014-02-2018%2C%2019%2034%2004.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: Would you be able to share your code? Could be something related to how often you are refreshing the collection view data and or the way in which the collection view gets its data source.

Comment: If I remove a vertical constraint from the last cell it begins to work so it is not related to the datasource. The datasource values are constant.

Comment: Make sure your constraints are related to the superview and not to the safe area zone.

Comment: I will give it a try but I recall them being linked to the supervise. I’ve added a video of what is happening.

Comment: @BogdanOnu The collectionview constraints were indeed linked to the safe area but changing it didn't fix it.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the collection view's contentOffset property.

Comment: No, it still seems to be related to the last cell. If I remove the cell from the collectionView it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cells were autoresizing but I also had the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout delegate method `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` implemented in a view controller extension.

It worked fine for a while but when I required self sizing cells, I forgot to remove the delegate.